# TYPO3 @dontverifyrequesthash

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-9.x

In one of our extensions we have this snippet:

```
 /** 
  * action main 
  * 
  * @return void 
  * @dontverifyrequesthash 
  */
```

TYPO3 Version 8 with PHP 7.1 works. 
TYPO3 Version 9 with PHP 7.2 we get this error:

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@dontverifyrequesthash" in method X\Y\Controller\Z::mainAction() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

The annotation `@dontverifyrequesthash` died before TYPO3 version 6.2, so you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks, we did not see that. Is there anything official in the TYPO3 logs?

Comment: I have just looked in the docs and it's wrong there. In short: With the usage of the new property mapper (by default since 6.2) the annotations `@dontvalidate` and `@dontverifyrequesthash` are no longer recognized by the property mapper. You only can use `@ignorevalidation $object`.